# Why is IE8 running a jQuery.click function on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-events

```
$('.consejosTab').live("click", function(){
    window.location = 'http://encuentratrabajoonline.es/consejos/';
    console.log('clicked')
});
```

Can anyone explain to me what this code is being initialized on page load, but only in IE8? I've disabled all triggers and confirmed that there are no other click functions being run that could be interfering with this. This code sits within a document.ready, and is the only click function that seems to trigger on the page load.

EDIT:

In an interesting twist, in IE8 the event.target for the click function is the window. In IE8 it returns as the URL for the page, but in everything else it appears as the actual element that it was clicked on?

Comment: Does anything call `.click()` (with no arguments) or `.trigger('click')` on page load?

Comment: Is there an initialisation bit of code on that tab that runs $(".consejosTab").click() or similar. It might be a 'false' click fired somewhere else (assuming you aren't accidentally clicking the element in IE8!)

Comment: Use the debugger to find the call stack.

Comment: I've already confirmed there are no trigger or click functions anywhere else in the site that directly relate to the cnsejosTab element.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to troubleshoot this is to log the element that was clicked.

```
$('.consejosTab').live("click", function(evt){
    console.log(evt.target);
});
```

You will then be able to see what element is being clicked (and the page won't reload). I assume you have more than one element labeled consejosTab.

You can also put a breakpoint on that console.log line, and browse through the call stack.

Comment: I like the idea of using the event target, there is only one instance of this class on this page, and I can confirm that there are no other click functions referencing this particular element.